# Corona Lua Questions

Tags: coronasdk

I just got started with Corona yesterday and love what I have seen thus far. I have run into a few issues with which I would like some help

- It looks like a Corona app is set up to shut down as soon as the Home button on the phone  is clicked.  I have come across hints that this can be chanaged from build.settings but nothing more specific.  What needs to be specified there?#
- I imagine there are pause and resume events associated with when the app gets back/fore grounded?

I'd much appreciate any help with this

Comment: Can the title be rephrased so to make it more relevant, maybe something like *corona application suspend issue*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iOS devices, add these in *build.setting*.

```
iphone =
{
  plist =
  {
    UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend = false
  }
}
```

Android will automatically suspend when home button is pressed.
See [here](http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2012/02/20/kindle-unable-handle-incoming-call-interrupt#comment-94532).

---

For application suspend/resume handling, you can try:

```
function onSystemEvent( event )
  if ( event.type == "applicationSuspend" ) then
     --do stuff
  elseif ( event.type == "applicationResume" ) then
     --do stuff
  end
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "system", onSystemEvent )
```

See [here](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/index/eventtype-0).

Comment: Apologies for the belated "thankyou".  In the end I abandoned Corona (much though I liked many of its features) and used Titanium instead.  I guess it should come as no surprise - Titanium is nice but far from perfect.  I suspect that in the longer term one simply has to develop for the target platform rather than something that uses an intermediate layer of abstraction.

Comment: The deeper you go, you will start to demand more power and flexibility from your tools, and you will need platform specific code to do that. I have gone with native Android code myself, cheers.